# Sort function breaks when value is null/undefined (React, javascript)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting

I prepared a sort functions for my set of data:

```
const sortHelper = (key, order) => {
  return (compare1, compare2) => {
    if (!compare1.hasOwnProperty(key) || !compare2.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      return 0;
    }
    const varA = compare1[key].toString().toUpperCase();
    const varB = compare2[key].toString().toUpperCase();
    let comparison = 0;
    if (varA > varB) {
      comparison = 1;
    } else if (varA < varB) {
      comparison = -1;
    }
    return order === 'DESC' ? comparison * -1 : comparison;
  };
};

export const sortData = (data, sortOrder) => {
  if (!sortOrder) {
    return data;
  }
  const { sortingCriteria, direction } = sortOrder;
  return data.sort(sortHelper(sortingCriteria[0], direction));
};
```

Unfortunately it breaks, when some value is null or undefined. I tried to this like this:

```
const varA = compare1[key].toString().toUpperCase();
```

But still it breaks.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a default empty string for [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values.

```
const varA = (compare1[key] === 0 ? 0 : compare1[key] || '').toString().toUpperCase();
```

If you ndo not need only strings, you could take the type directly an use the empty string as default value for falsy value who are not zero.

```
const varA = compare1[key] === 0 ? 0 : compare1[key] || '';
```

Comment: But in such cace 0 will be false as well so it will change 0 to ''

Comment: TypeError: (intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value).toUpperCase is not a function

Comment: that is stange. it should works this way. have you added some other braces?

Comment: nope, just like you added, and the error is there when I sort number values, with string values it's ok

Comment: OK my bad, removed toString() by accident but now noticed that this alghoritm doesnt sort properly, as all values are strings so numbers are storted badly (500 is before 1000 etc :( )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203652/discussion-between-nina-scholz-and-heisenberg7584).